# Which odbc connector to use?

Tags: php, mysql, odbc, connector, mysql-odbc-connector

I am getting this error from the following code:

$result = odbc_connect("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=$database_name",$database_username, $database_password);

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error:
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source
>   name not found, and no default driver
>   specified, SQL state IM002 in
>   SQLConnect in /dbconnect.php on line
>   xx odbc not connected

I am using **MySQL** version *5.1.41-3ubuntu12.3*

My phpinfo gives the following output:

```
Additional .ini files parsed /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/odbc.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/pdo_odbc.ini  

odbc
----

ODBC Support            enabled <br>
```

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to MySQL?  Why not use either PDO or MySQLi?

Comment: This is an already existing source, so I have to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have an ODBC driver installed. http://packages.ubuntu.com/hardy/unixodbc